# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.accessibleConstructor

Tags: java, spring, maven, sap-cloud-sdk

I took this [extensibility scenario 352] (https://extensibilityexplorer.cfapps.eu10.hana.ondemand.com/ExtensibilityExplorer/#/ExtScenario/352), [second app] (https://help.sap.com/viewer/4316f97a90ff48948fb7f212ecabf964/SHIP/en-US/413ac667f3dc4cab844d21d088171854.html) as backbone. Then, I changed the POM file to migrate to SDK v03.
By doing so, I managed to build my project, but I am facing issue at Neo deployment.

Remark: I had to as using the as-is POM I didn´t make a way to build the custom VDM.

My POM file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.sap.susntar</groupId>
    <artifactId>cscc</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1</version>

    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <main.basedir>${basedir}/../..</main.basedir>
        <m2eclipse.wtp.contextRoot>/</m2eclipse.wtp.contextRoot>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.sap.cloud.sdk</groupId>
                <artifactId>sdk-bom</artifactId>
                <version>3.11.0</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
                <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Compile -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Provided (for embedded war support) -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Test -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
<!--    Added trying to fix an issue at startup app-->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
<!--            <version>5.2.3.RELEASE</version>-->
        </dependency>

        <!-- S/4HANA Cloud SDK -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sap.cloud.sdk.s4hana</groupId>
            <artifactId>s4hana-all</artifactId>
<!--            <version>3.11.0</version>-->
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sap.cloud.s4hana.datamodel/odata-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sap.cloud.sdk.datamodel</groupId>
            <artifactId>odata-core</artifactId>
<!--            <version>3.11.0</version>-->
        </dependency>
        <!--  added to generate custom VDM classes -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!--  added to generate custom VDM classes -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>neo</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <dependencies>
<!--                <dependency>-->
<!--                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>-->
<!--                    <artifactId>spring-boot-legacy</artifactId>-->
<!--                    <version>1.1.0.RELEASE</version>-->
<!--                </dependency>-->
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                    <scope>provided</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
                    <exclusions>
                        <!-- The assembled war must not include any SLF4J related JARs
                            see https://help.hana.ondemand.com/help/frameset.htm?e6e8ccd3bb571014b6afdc54744eef4d.html -->
                        <exclusion>
                            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                        </exclusion>
                        <exclusion>
                            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
                            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                        </exclusion>
                    </exclusions>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform</groupId>
                    <artifactId>scp-neo</artifactId>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>local</id>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform</groupId>
                    <artifactId>scp-cf</artifactId>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.sap.cloud.sdk.datamodel</groupId>
                <artifactId>odata-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.11.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>generate-consumption</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <inputDirectory>${project.basedir}/edmx</inputDirectory>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/vdm</outputDirectory>
                            <deleteOutputDirectory>true</deleteOutputDirectory>
                            <packageName>com.sunstar.vdm</packageName>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <!-- added to generate custom VDM classes -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>add-source</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sources>
                                <source>${project.build.directory}/vdm</source>
                            </sources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>

            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

The error log:

```
FILE_TYPE:DAAA96DE-B0FB-4c6e-AF7B-A445F5BF9BE2
FILE_ID:1580651659104
ENCODING:[UTF8|NWCJS:ASCII]
RECORD_SEPARATOR:124
COLUMN_SEPARATOR:35
ESC_CHARACTER:92
COLUMNS:Time|TZone|Severity|Logger|ACH|User|Thread|Bundle name|JPSpace|JPAppliance|JPComponent|Tenant Alias|DSR Root Context ID|DSR Transaction|DSR Connection|DSR Counter|Text|
SEVERITY_MAP:FINEST|Information|FINER|Information|FINE|Information|CONFIG|Information|DEBUG|Information|PATH|Information|INFO|Information|WARNING|Warning|ERROR|Error|SEVERE|Error|FATAL|Error
HEADER_END


2020 02 02 13:54:37#+00#ERROR#org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext##anonymous#localhost-startStop-1#na#s0018275953trial#cscc4#web##na#na#na#na#Error during ServletContainerInitializer processing javax.servlet.ServletException: Failed to instantiate WebApplicationInitializer class
    at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5245)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:754)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:730)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:985)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1857)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:836)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.accessibleConstructor(Ljava/lang/Class;[Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/reflect/Constructor;
    at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:155)
    ... 12 common frames omitted
|
2020 02 02 13:54:37#+00#ERROR#org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext##anonymous#localhost-startStop-1#na#s0018275953trial#cscc4#web##na#na#na#na#Context [/cscc-0.0.1] startup failed due to previous errors |
```

Could you guy tell me which dependency I forgot?

Pietro

Answer (score 1):

The `org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.accessibleConstructor` method is available only in the recent `spring-core` dependency versions. And since in your pom file, the `spring-core` dependency version gets resolved to `4.3.9.RELEASE`, this causes the problem.

A quick fix is to update your parent `spring-boot-starter-parent` to version `2.2.4.RELEASE` instead of `1.5.4.RELEASE`.
This automatically updates the `spring-core` dependency version too.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I am getting the similar error now, though i can find the method in the downloaded maven jar. Any other fix done ?

Comment: Same here but only appears occasionally. I'm on Spring 5.3.x. When I experience the error I build my project with the old Spring 4.3.x that I upgraded from, then I build again mit 5.3.x and the error is gone.